# Excel has doubled the size of all control on a form and cannot go back to normal

Tags: excel, vba

I have two monitors, one is 2k, the other 4k and both running on recommended windows scaling (125%, 150%).

I have a spreadsheet with two forms. I have just edited one form on my larger screen and after saving it has almost doubled the size of everything, as shown below is one section from a form I have updated, the other untouched from the same project.

When I copy/paste controls from one to the other, it doubles/halves in size, so something in the form has set scaling to be wrong.

The font and sizes are both exactly the same, zoom is normal at 100 and there are no other options I can see that affect scaling. I literally edited then saved and it just broke.

I know Excel completely knacks up when you use different monitors, but to date my forms have been ok.

Any idea how to get the size back to normal. I've even reset my monitors to both be 2k but it just won't fix anything unless i do something daft like set zoom to 50%.

thanks. This is latest Excel from 365.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Tools - Options - General - Form Grid Settings

Comment: This shouldn’t apply with form controls but worth noting activex controls are notorious for resizing/moving/doubling up icons with different screen resolution.

Comment: Thanks, nothing seems to budge. So I've had to revert to an old git copy, drop all my screens to the same resolution with 100% scaling. It's just crazy it's 2020 and scaling is still such an issue and literally saving a file breaks a form's scale. Or maybe it's about time VBA got dropped and replaced somehow with a scriptable .Net project system for Office tools.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, having the VBA editor on a 4k screen with scaling and a 2k screen as primary. Every time a previewed the form, the size kept on (roughly) doubling. Also Office 365, so basically the latest version...

Anyways, I was able to revert the effect by changing the zoom property of the form (I used 50 but I assume it does not matter) and then resizing the form itself. After resizing, the zoom was applied and after setting zoom back to 100 the original size was restored.

Hopefully this helps anyone facing the same issue.